# I want to redirect to specified HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a index page inside of it a form. I put in it phone number and email and quantity and it sends a request to my email. The problem I'm facing
is after I click proceed, it stays on same page, and nothing changes.
I want when I click procced to redirect me to specified HTML file.

The HTML part is:

```
  <div style="opacity: 0.9;" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background: #002b49;">
          <div class="modal-header" style="border: none;">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> </h5>
            <button type="button" style="background: none; border: none; color: #fff;" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="defaultForm-group">
                          <div class="field calculator-price      " data-target="field" data-component="calculator-price-field" data-field="price">
                        <div class="field-input">
                    <div class="field-prefix">
                            <div class="field-prefix-wrapper">
                              <span class="field-prefix-label" data-component="field-prefix" data-related-name="price-prefix"><img height="14px" src="img/incoming-call.png"></span>
                            </div>
                          </div>      
                    <input type="number" class="defaultInput" id="tnumber" placeholder="Telephone no" name="price" step="10" min="0" required="" autocomplete="off">
    
                        </div>
            
                      </div>
                          <div class="field calculator-currency" data-target="field" data-field="currency">
                        <div class="field-input">
                        
                        <div class="field-prefix">
                        
                              <span class=""><img height="14px" src="img/email.png"></span>
                    
                          </div>   
                        
                          <div class="defaultSelec defaultSelect--form ">
                     <input class="defaultSelect-select" name="currency" id="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address"></div>
    
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          
          <p class="error_rep2" style="color: #fff;"></p>
           <p class="submitinfo2" style="color: #fff;"></p>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="mproceed" class="btn btn--secondary  btn--large">Proceed</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The PHP part:

```
if(isset($email)){
$send = SimpleMail::make()
    ->setTo('chacha@gmail.com', 'Elie Services')
    ->setFrom($email, $fname)
    ->setSubject($fname,$lname)
    ->setMessage($msgbody)
   // ->setReplyTo($replyEmail, $replyName)
    ->setHtml()
    ->setWrap(100)
    ->send();

if ($send) {
  //  echo 'Your Message Sent Successfully!';
header("location: success.html");
} else {
    echo 'An error occurred. We could not send email';
   $page = "success.html";
$sec = "3";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
}
}else {
    
    $page = "success.html";
$sec = "1";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
    
}

?>
```

Please, when I press proceed I want to get redirected fully to success.html.

Comment: You know, Java and Javascript **are different languages**

Comment: You say you have a form but I don't see `<form>` anywhere.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 0):

As one of the above replies mentions, you don't have a `<form>` tag anywhere. The Proceed button is just a regular button, and won't do anything (as you have observed). To get this to do what you want, first you will need something like this at the top:

```
<form action='process.php' method='POST'>
```

(Replace process.php with the name of your PHP file.) At the bottom of your HTML, put a `</form>` closing tag. In the `<button>` tag for Proceed, change the `type` to submit. That will cause the PHP to be called. In the PHP, you will need to use `$_POST` to retrieve the INPUT field values from the form. Nothing will automatically populate values in the PHP variables.